# pipe one long line as multiple lines

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, awk, zsh

Say I have a bunch of XML files which contain no newlines, but basically contain a long list of records, delimited by `</record><record>`

If the delimiter were `</record>\n<record>` I would be able to do something like `cat *.xml | grep xyz | wc -l` to count instances of records of interest, because cat would emit the records one per line.

Is there a way to write `SOMETHING *.xml | grep xyz | wc -l` where `SOMETHING` can stream out the records one per line? I tried using `awk` for this but couldn't find a way to avoid streaming the whole file into memory.

Hopefully the question is clear enough :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a little ugly, but it works:

```
sed 's|</record>|</record>\
|g' *.xml | grep xyz | wc -l
```

(Yes, I know I could make it a little bit shorter, but only at the cost of clarity.)

Comment: This works very well, much faster than my `awk` version, but to be clear, it causes `sed` to read the whole file into memory, correct? Is there a more "streaming" version? What if the XML file is a gig in size?

Comment: @nicolas: You could use Perl and the `read` function (not the `<>` operator) to read chunks of a file, insert newlines, and write it out. The only tricky bit is ensuring that if Block 13 is unlucky enough to end part way through the `</record><record>` sequence, you keep the trailing context for processing with the next part. Note in particular that if Block 13 ends with `<` or `</`, you have to keep those characters around in case Block 14 starts `/record><record>` or `record><record>`. I don't think there's a standard utility to do this sort of splitting; most Unix utilities work on lines.

Comment: slightly more readable: `sed $'s|</record>|&\n|g' ...` -- uses the bash construct [`$''`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to enable escape sequences in strings.

Comment: @nicolaskruchten: there *might* be a way to do what you ask: `tr '>' '\012'` will split up the line, but I don't know whether it reads the whole line into memory at once. If not, then we could splice the `record`s back together with sed, then grep, then wc.

Comment: @glen jackman: interesting, but it doesn't work for me and I suspect it's not very portable.

Answer (score 2):

If your record body has no character like `<` or `/` or `>`, then you may try this:

```
grep -E -o 'SEARCH_STRING[^<]*</record>' *.xml| wc -l
```

or

```
grep -E -o 'SEARCH_STRING[^/]*/record>' *.xml| wc -l
```

or

```
grep -E -o 'SEARCH_STRING[^>]*>' *.xml| wc -l
```

Comment: OK, this is very nice, and does address my specific issue about grepping through records, but I was looking for a more generic solution to breaking apart the long line and emitting the records into a pipe one at a time, a-la the `sed` version in the other answer :) Still looking for something that doesn't load it all into memory first!

Comment: Additionally, the `sed` version in the other answer is much faster, I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach using **xsltproc**, **grep**, and **wc**. Warning: I am new to XSL so I can be dangerous :-). Here is my count_records.xsl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" />      <!-- Output text, not XML -->
  <xsl:template match="record">     <!-- Search for "record" node -->
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/> <!-- Output: contents of node record -->
    <xsl:text>                      <!-- Output: a new line -->
    </xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On my Mac, I found a command line tool called **xsltproc**, which read instructions from an XSL file, process XML files. So the command would be:

```
xsltproc count_records.xsl *.xml | grep SEARCH_STRING | wc -l
```

- The **xsltproc** command displays the text in each  node, one line at a time
- The **grep** command filters out the text you are interested in
- Finally, the **wc** command produces the count

Answer (score 1):

You may also try `xmlstarlet` for gig-sized files:

```
# cf. http://niftybits.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/working-with-huge-xml-files-tools-of-the-trade/

xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "count(//record[contains(normalize-space(text()),'xyz')])" -n *.xml | 
    awk '{n+=$1} END {print n}'

xmlstarlet sel -T -t -v "count(//record[contains(normalize-space(text()),'xyz')])" -n *.xml | 
    paste -s -d '+' /dev/stdin | bc
```